# slider revolution white margin on top of slide

Tags: wordpress, slider, margin, revolution-slider

I have a white space (margin) on top of my slide.
I searched for many hours, and tried everything but did not find a solution.
Most topics around this problem do not have a clear solution so this might be caused by the theme (flatsome) right?

link to site > [cosmosdesign.be](http://cosmosdesign.be)

Comment: can you add screenshot to look more

Comment: Try putting `margin: 0;` on the body element.

Comment: got it fixed by installing yellow pencile and adding margin 0

Answer (score 0):

See screenshot and add css in your theme.
padding-top:0px
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sQ57.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this will work please add style in your css**

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    top: -45px;
}
```